# How to calculate required stack size for tree of called functions in GCC

Tags: gcc, stack

Is it possible to determine the demand a non recursive function on the stack without external computation, right in the text of the program? I need this to allocate a memory resource for the thread in very small micro-controllers, such as AVR. And I need know this before function calling. Directive --stack-usage is very non informative, unfortunately. Or I something do not understand?

Comment: in gcc there is the -fstack-usage option; it reports the stack usage of each function  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html . Another guy wrote a script to compute the stack usage for the call tree https://github.com/PeterMcKinnis/WostCaseStack

Comment: @MichaelMoser Yes, but the received values do not take into account nested calls.

Comment: I thought it would be better to advance the compiler.

Comment: @MichaelMoser Thank You Michael. I like Python.

Comment: @MichaelMoser Hello Michael. Excuse my perseverance. Maybe you can answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606130/how-to-customise-the-automatic-preambles-for-interrupt-in-avr-gcc Is this possible without interfering into the program of the compiler? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the address of a passed argument yields it's place on the stack. Therefore running this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_fun(int dummy);
int get_stack_space(int dummy);

int main(void)
{
    int dummy = 0;

    my_fun(dummy);

    return 0;
}

void my_fun(int dummy)
{
    // do stuff
    printf("%d\n", get_stack_space((int)&dummy));
    return;
}

int get_stack_space(int dummy)
{
    return dummy - (int)&dummy;
}
```

should get you the distance in bytes on the stack between the point of calling my_fun() and calling get_stack_space(). Hope it helps.

Edit: on x86 you get the distance + a machine word for the push of the return address when calling my_fun() + a machine word for the push of ebp at the start of my_fun()

Comment: Sorry, I not very detailed asked the question. I need this to allocate a memory resource for the thread in very small micro-controllers, such as AVR. It need know before function calling.